# CSS calling a style

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS here but its not working :(

Here is the CSS

```
.wpsc-product .hentry{
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 0 !important;
    position: relative;
}
```

this is what I am trying to call

```
<article id="post-60" class="post-60 wpsc-product type-wpsc-product status-publish hentry">
```

how would I apply to this article and it has to invlice wpsc-product because thats what I am targeting.

Comment: are you trying to override another existing style or something applied by a script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.wpsc-product .hentry` is a combinator selector which will match any element with a class of hentry that has an ancestor with a class of wpsc-product, like

```
<article class="wpsc-product"><section class="hentry"></section></article>
```

You want `.wpsc-product.hentry` (no space)

Answer (score 1):

remove the space in your css selector

```
.wpsc-product.hentry { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

That `article` element will only get the CSS rule you have if it is inside another element with the `wpsc-product` class, because   (an empty space) is actually an operator in CSS, meaning that the second selector is a descendent (inside) the first.

To select elements that have *both* classes, use `.wpsc-product.hentry` as the selector. Concatenation of selectors requires all of them on the element.

Answer (score 0):

To adress a tag that has more than one class, you should use css selectors like:

```
class1.class2.class3 { ... }
```

In your case:

```
.wpsc-product.hentry
```